# Installing 64 bit version of Boost C++ in Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, 64-bit

I am trying to compile 64 bit version of Boost for Visual C++ 2010.

I am running this command:

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage
```

However I get a bunch of errors:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Were I to guess, I'd say head to your vs install folder, the vc subdir, and run `vcvarsall.bat x64` then try it again. It seems like boost can't find the ms compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do these steps:

1) Start a 64 bit cmd.exe

2) Move to the Boost root directory; i.e. where you unzipped the files.

3) Run "boostrap.bat" (This creates b2.exe and bjam.exe in the root directory).

4) b2 as you currently do

I suspect you might be not doing (1) and (3).

Comment: Both "boostrap.bat" and "b2.exe" need to be run in a 64bit version of cmd.exe?  How do I know that the cmd.exe is 64bit?

Comment: echo PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE is one way. It will be AMD64 for 64bit cmd.exe, and x86 for 32bit cmd.exe

Comment: @Bathsheba, could you be incorrect? Both the 32- and 64-bit compilers should be able to target both 32- and 64-bit architectures. Only difference (afaik) is that a 64-bit compiler cannot be run on a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the libs, you can get them from this site for "all" the VC versions.
http://boost.teeks99.com/

Comment: +1 this is indeed helpful to get you started, but, you really ought to learn how to build Boost yourself. Then you insulate yourself from changes to your compiler / platform / architecture or even stl vendor choices that the cited link may not support.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

can be solved by running the following batch file:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio #\VC\vcvarsall.bat`